# Pytorch lstm model very high loss in eval mode against train mode

Tags: lstm, pytorch

I am using a Siamese network with a 2-layer lstm encoder and `dropout=0.5` to classify string similarity.

For each batch, I am randomly generating similar and dissimilar strings. So, the pytorch model cannot overfit to the training data.

When the model is in `train()` mode, loss is 0.0932, but, if the model is in `eval()` mode, loss is 0.613.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Here is the total code for this model. The code works on gpu instance of colab without any modification.

```
import torch
# torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)

from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable

import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import time

# from google.colab import files
# files.upload()

chars = r' !"#&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# len(chars)

char_to_id = {k:v for k,v in zip(chars, range(len(chars)))}
char_to_id['<pad>'] = len(char_to_id)
#char_to_id
# len(char_to_id)

#char_to_id['<pad>']

class opt:
    embedding_dims = 20
    vocab_size = 81
    hidden_dims = 128
    num_layers = 2
    beta_1 = 0.9
    learning_rate = 0.0001
    clip_value = 1
    lstm_bidir = True
    lstm_dropout = 0.5
    padding_idx = char_to_id['<pad>']

class LSTMEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, opt):
        super(LSTMEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.embed_size = opt.embedding_dims
        self.hidden_size = opt.hidden_dims
        self.num_layers = opt.num_layers
        self.bidir = opt.lstm_bidir
        self.padding_idx = opt.padding_idx
        if self.bidir:
            self.direction = 2
        else: self.direction = 1
        self.dropout = opt.lstm_dropout

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=opt.embedding_dims, hidden_size=self.hidden_size, dropout=self.dropout,
                            num_layers=self.num_layers, bidirectional=self.bidir)

    def initHiddenCell(self, batch_size):
        rand_hidden = Variable(torch.zeros(self.direction * self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        rand_cell = Variable(torch.zeros(self.direction * self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        return rand_hidden, rand_cell

    def forward(self, input1, hidden, cell):
        # input1 = self.embedding(input1)
        # input_lengths = torch.as_tensor(input_lengths, dtype=torch.int64, device='cpu')
        # input1 = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(input1, input_lengths, batch_first=False, enforce_sorted=False)
        output, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(input1, (hidden, cell))
        return output, hidden, cell

class Siamese_lstm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, opt):
        super(Siamese_lstm, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = LSTMEncoder(opt)

        self.input_dim = int(1 * self.encoder.direction * self.encoder.hidden_size)

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.input_dim, int(self.input_dim/2)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(int(self.input_dim/2), int(self.input_dim/4)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(int(self.input_dim/4), 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=opt.vocab_size, embedding_dim=opt.embedding_dims,
                                      padding_idx=opt.padding_idx, max_norm=None, scale_grad_by_freq=False, sparse=False)

    def forward(self, s1, s2, s1_lengths, s2_lengths):
        batch_size = s1.size()[1]
        if device.type == 'cuda':
            max_length = torch.cuda.LongTensor(torch.cat((s1_lengths, s2_lengths))).max().item()
        else:
            max_length = torch.LongTensor(torch.cat((s1_lengths, s2_lengths))).max().item()

        # init hidden, cell
        h1, c1 = self.encoder.initHiddenCell(batch_size)
        h2, c2 = self.encoder.initHiddenCell(batch_size)

        s1 = self.embedding(s1)
        s1 = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(s1, s1_lengths, batch_first=False, enforce_sorted=False)
        h1 = h1.to(device)
        c1 = c1.to(device)
        v1, h1, c1 = self.encoder(s1, h1, c1)

        s2 = self.embedding(s2)
        s2 = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(s2, s2_lengths, batch_first=False, enforce_sorted=False)
        h2 = h2.to(device)
        c2 = c2.to(device)
        v2, h2, c2 = self.encoder(s2, h2, c2)

        v1, l1 = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(v1, batch_first=False, total_length=max_length)
        v2, l2 = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(v2, batch_first=False, total_length=max_length)
        # print(v1)
        if device.type == 'cuda':
            batch_indices = torch.cuda.LongTensor(range(batch_size))
        else:
            batch_indices = torch.LongTensor(range(batch_size))
        v1 = v1[l1-1,batch_indices,:]
        v2 = v2[l2-1,batch_indices,:]
        # features = torch.cat((v1,v2), 1)
        features = abs(v1-v2)
        output = self.classifier(features)

        return output

def create_similar_strings(chars, str_length = 1000, replace_frac = 0.01, delete_frac=0.01):
    # creating a random string
    str1 = np.random.choice(chars,str_length)
    str2 = str1
    # randomly calculate the number of characters from above string to replace or delete
    rand_num1 = np.random.randint(0,int(replace_frac*str_length)+1)
    rand_num2 = np.random.randint(0,int(delete_frac*str_length)+1)
    # print(rand_num1, rand_num2)
    # calculate the positions at which to replace the characters in str2
    idx = np.random.choice(range(len(str2)), rand_num1)
    str2 = [y if x not in idx else np.random.choice(chars, 1)[0] for x,y in enumerate(str2)]
    # calculate the positions at which to delete the characters in str2
    idx = np.random.choice(range(len(str2)), rand_num2)
    str2 = [y for x,y in enumerate(str2) if x not in idx]
    return np.random.choice([''.join(str1), ''.join(str2)], 2, replace=False)

def create_dissimilar_strings(chars, str_length = 1000, max_len_diff_frac = 0.05):
    # creating a random string
    str1 = ''.join(np.random.choice(chars,str_length))
    length = np.random.randint(int(str_length*(1-max_len_diff_frac)), int(str_length*(1+max_len_diff_frac)))
    str2 = ''.join(np.random.choice(chars, length))
    return np.random.choice([str1, str2], 2, replace=False)

#str1, str2 = create_similar_strings([x for x in chars], 10, 0.1, 0.1)
#str1, str2, len(str1), len(str2)

#str1, str2 = create_dissimilar_strings([x for x in chars], 10, 0.2)
#str1, str2, len(str1), len(str2)

def random_generate_strings(chars, str_length=1000, replace_frac=0.01, delete_frac=0.01, max_len_diff_frac = 0.05):
    if np.random.choice([True, False],1)[0]:
        str1, str2 = create_similar_strings(chars, str_length, replace_frac, delete_frac)
        label = [1]
    else:
        str1, str2 = create_dissimilar_strings(chars, str_length, max_len_diff_frac)
        label = [0]
    return str1, str2, label

def random_generate_batch(chars, batch_size=1, min_str_length=10, max_str_length=1000, replace_frac=0.01, delete_frac=0.01,
                          max_len_diff_frac = 0.05):
    strings1 = ['']*batch_size
    strings2 = ['']*batch_size
    labels = [0]*batch_size
    for i in range(batch_size):
        str_length = np.random.randint(min_str_length, max_str_length)
        str1, str2, label = random_generate_strings(chars, str_length, replace_frac, delete_frac, max_len_diff_frac)
        strings1[i] = [char_to_id[x] for x in str1]
        strings2[i] = [char_to_id[x] for x in str2]
        labels[i] = label
    len_strs1 = [len(x) for x in strings1]
    len_strs2 = [len(x) for x in strings2]
    max_length = max([len(x) for x in strings1+strings2])
    temp_list = [char_to_id['<pad>']]*max_length
    strings1 = [(x+temp_list)[0:max_length] for x in strings1]
    strings2 = [(x+temp_list)[0:max_length] for x in strings2]
    train_batch_a = torch.t(torch.LongTensor(strings1))
    train_batch_b = torch.t(torch.LongTensor(strings2))
    train_labels = torch.t(torch.Tensor(labels))
    len_strs1 = torch.LongTensor(len_strs1)
    len_strs2 = torch.LongTensor(len_strs2)
    return train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2

train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2 = random_generate_batch([x for x in chars], 3, 5, 6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.05)
print(train_batch_a.size(), train_batch_b.size(), train_labels.size(), len_strs1.size(), len_strs2.size())
print(train_batch_a, '\n', train_batch_b, '\n', train_labels, '\n', len_strs1, '\n', len_strs2)

def train_one_step(model, optimizer, criterion, train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2):
    model.train()

    output = model.forward(Variable(train_batch_a), Variable(train_batch_b), len_strs1, len_strs2)
    output = output.squeeze()
    train_labels = Variable(train_labels).squeeze()
    # print(output, output.size(), train_labels, train_labels.size())

    loss = criterion(output, train_labels)
    print(loss.item())

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


def test_one_step(model, criterion, train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2):
    model.eval()
    output = model.forward(Variable(train_batch_a), Variable(train_batch_b), len_strs1, len_strs2)
    output = output.squeeze()
    train_labels = Variable(train_labels).squeeze()
    # print(output, output.size(), train_labels, train_labels.size())
    loss = criterion(output, train_labels)
    print(loss.item())

model = Siamese_lstm(opt)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
# device = torch.device("cpu")
device

model = model.to(device)

# criterion = nn.MSELoss()
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.000001)
# optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9)

n = 10
for i in range(n):
    train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2 = random_generate_batch([x for x in chars], batch_size = 3, min_str_length = 10, max_str_length = 500,
                                                                                             replace_frac = 0.07, delete_frac = 0.07, max_len_diff_frac = 0.1)
    # print(train_batch_a, '\n', train_batch_b, '\n', train_labels)
    # print(train_batch_a.size(), '\n', train_batch_b.size(), '\n', train_labels.size())
    # print(len_strs1, len_strs2)
    train_batch_a = train_batch_a.to(device)
    train_batch_b = train_batch_b.to(device)
    train_labels = train_labels.to(device)
    len_strs1 = len_strs1.to(device)
    len_strs2 = len_strs2.to(device)

    train_one_step(model, optimizer, criterion, train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2)
    # test_one_step(model, criterion, train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2)

to = time.time()
with torch.set_grad_enabled(False):
    train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2 = random_generate_batch([x for x in chars], batch_size = 1000, min_str_length = 10, max_str_length = 500,
                                                                                             replace_frac = 0.07, delete_frac = 0.07, max_len_diff_frac = 0.1)
    train_batch_a = train_batch_a.to(device)
    train_batch_b = train_batch_b.to(device)
    train_labels = train_labels.to(device)
    len_strs1 = len_strs1.to(device)
    len_strs2 = len_strs2.to(device)
    # print(len_strs1, len_strs2)
    test_one_step(model, criterion, train_batch_a, train_batch_b, train_labels, len_strs1, len_strs2)
print(round(time.time()-to,2))

# 0.0932, 0.613

# torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/content/text_similarity_v4(gpu).pth')

# model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/text_similarity_v4(gpu).pth'))
```

In the test_one_step function, we only need to change the model.eval() to model.train() to observe the difference after training the model.

Comment: can you post your code so that people see what you do exactly? What did you try so far?